# Trying to setup Jansy-bootstrap offcanvas menu sliding in from the right

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I have setup everything and it all works fine when the menu is sliding in from the left, however I need it to slide in from the right. Currently the menu when used from the right, just appears rather than transitioning in.

if you have a look at the jsfiddle link you will see what I mean. comment out the right and use the left to see the difference between the two.

```
<div class="navmenu offcanvas-sm navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left">
Works

<div class="navmenu offcanvas-sm navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-right">
works but I doesn't slide, just appears.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1eddy87/8bgLs0bn/

*** UPDATE: Issue seems to only occur on firefox ***

Any ideas?

Comment: Works fine for me in both directions. What browser are you using?

Comment: @wickywills - Firefox on mac. Link to Jansy Bootstrap as a reference to those who don't know what it is. http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/examples/navmenu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well I've never used (or heard of) Jansy-bootstrap before, but a bit of a Google, and found [this](https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/issues/253), which makes sense.

Basically, it appears you need to add the following either directly into the Bootstrap CSS, or into your own CSS file (probably better, since I don't like changing core files for any framework!)

```
.navmenu-fixed-right {
   left: auto !important;
}
```

Seems a bit of a temporary patch to me though - would be best to notify the framework developer of this bug.

Can be seen working now in Firefox [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8bgLs0bn/4/)

Comment: Thanks heaps mate, I just assumed that the css would have been completed. Just goes to show, don't assume

Comment: @EddyAk - Always bugs with pretty much anything unfortunately. Would be worth mentioning it to the developer though, maybe they can do a proper fix and release a new version at a later date :)